# Surely it is a stupid syntax mistake but I am a beginner with sql: 1054. Unknown column Error

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1054

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
    INIZIO.idinizio AS id,
    inizio,
    fine,
    barca
FROM
    (
        (
        SELECT
            ID AS idinizio ,
            meta_value AS inizio,
            term_taxonomy_id AS barca
        FROM
            wp_posts
        INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON(
                ID = post_id AND post_type = 'tribe_events' AND meta_key = '_EventStartDate' AND(
                    post_status = 'publish' OR post_status = 'private'
                )
            )
        INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON(
                ID = object_id
            )
        ) AS INIZIO
INNER JOIN
        (
        SELECT
            ID AS idfine,
            meta_value AS fine
        FROM
            wp_posts
        INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON(
                ID = post_id AND post_type = 'tribe_events' AND meta_key = '_EventEndDate' AND(
                    post_status = 'publish' OR post_status = 'private'
                )
            )
        ) AS FINE
ON (idinizio = idfine)
)
```

And when I run it I get the following error:

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'idinizio' in 'field list'
```

[Image of my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zg4E1.jpg)

Why am I getting this error?

Surely it will be a beginner's mistake in the subquery or in some table alias.

**UPDATE:**

.. I realized now that I have reversed all the AS clauses ..
I fixed and now gives me this error:

```
#1054 - Colonna sconosciuta 'posts.idinizio' in 'on clause'
```

**UPDATE:**
I made the table prefixes wrong and I fixed it, now everything works, thank you very much for making me notice errors!

Comment: The column `idinizio` doesn't appear in any of your tables.

Comment: What version of MySQL? If 8+, you have access to CTE (http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cte/) which will make this query much less complex.

Comment: And you also don't have `barca` in your inner selects. And two `meta_value`s. As soon as you alias a column, the original name no longer exists to the outer pieces of your query.

Comment: I made some mistakes as a beginner I corrected, keep giving me that mistake, surely another nonsense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace `idinizio` column with `ID` as `ON (INIZIO.ID = FINE.idfine)` at the bottom part, since you already aliased that column as `ID` in the above inner query.

Comment: I made some mistakes as a beginner I corrected, keep giving me that mistake, surely another nonsense